# Hibernate unbound type and no explicit target entity when using generic

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have the following two classes:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "criteria") 
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = AbstractCriteria.TYPE, discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class AbstractCriteria<T> implements Serializable {

   public static final String TYPE = "type";

   ...
   @Column(name = "clazz") private Class<T> clazz;
   ...

   protected AbstractCriteria(Class<T> clazz) {
      this.clazz = Preconditions.checkNotNull(clazz);
   }
   ...

   public abstract Predicate<T> evaluate(T value);
}

@Entity 
@DiscriminatorValue(CriteriaType.Values.DATETIME_IS_BETWEEN) 
public class DateTimeIsBetweenCriteria extends AbstractCriteria<DateTime> {
   ...
   public DateTimeIsBetweenCriteria() {
      super(DateTime.class);
   }
   ...


   @Override 
   public Predicate<DateTime> evaluate(DateTime value) {
      ...
   }
}
```

When I tried to save an instance of the DateTimeIsBetweenCriteria class, I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
Property ...AbstractCriteria.clazz has an unbound type and no explicit target entity.
Resolve this Generic usage issue or set an explicit target attribute (eg @OneToMany(target=) or use an explicit @Type
```

I need `clazz` for a method in `AbstractCriteria`, and `T` can be String, DateTime, Boolean, etc.

I was thinking about making `clazz` `@Transient`, but if I do that, I still have to have another column to identify which criteria to save so that when loading the criteria back from the database, I know which kind of criteria it is. I think this is kinda hacky.

Any ideas how I can resolve that exception without changing my design?

I appreciate your time a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my implementation to not using parameterized type:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "criteria") 
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = AbstractCriteria.TYPE, discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class AbstractCriteria implements Serializable {

  public static final String TYPE = "type";

  ...
  @Column(name = "clazz") private Class clazz;
  ...

  protected AbstractCriteria(Class clazz) {
     this.clazz = Preconditions.checkNotNull(clazz);
  }
  ...

  public abstract Predicate evaluate(Object value);
}

@Entity 
@DiscriminatorValue(CriteriaType.Values.DATETIME_IS_BETWEEN) 
public class DateTimeIsBetweenCriteria extends AbstractCriteria {
  ...
  public DateTimeIsBetweenCriteria() {
     super(DateTime.class);
  }
  ...


  @Override 
  public Predicate evaluate(Object value) {
     if (value instanceof DateTime) {
        // do evaluation and return here.
     } else {
        throw new UserDefinedException("...");
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in terms of generics you're on the right lines but you're trying to persist a class of type "Class". Databases don't have data type this can directly map to (hence your error), the closest I can think of is to use a string for the classname;

```
@Column (name="className")
private String classname;
```

and set with

```
.... setClassname (DateTime.getCanonicalName());
```

To retrieve the class;

```
Class.forName(classname);
```

But if I've got the right idea about what you are doing, you don't need to persist the class at all:  all DateTimeIsBetweenCriteria instances with operate on DateTime - it's a template parameter of the class, not the instance. You should persist your between dates and not the behavior of the class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it is not right that you can't persist Class in the database. You can declare the `clazz` column as a varchar and hibernate supports saving Class.

Comment: I stand corrected; this is not something I've ever encountered - thank you! Is the last part of the answer useful?

Comment: I don't have to save the `clazz`, however as I mentioned above. I need to use the `clazz` value for some calculation. If I don't save it (make it transient), when hibernate loads the criteria back, `clazz` is gonna be null.

Comment: This answer is a good start. You can make `clazz`transient and have a `getClassName` annotated with `@Column`: hibernate will call the getter when saving and call `setClassName` when loading. Just make`getClassName` to return T class name and `setClassName to do clazz = Class.forName(classname)`.

Comment: PCO: why did you down vote my question? It looks like people prefer downvoting other people's post on here.

Comment: I actually changed my implementation to not using param type `T`. I appreciate all the answers. However, please don't randomly downvote other people's post. If you don't wanna answer, don't comment plz.